# Complicated trig limits to infinity problem!?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{2-t+\sin t}{t+\cos t}$$

I don't know how to do this problem! I don't think you can use the squeeze theorem on it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Divide top and bottom by $t$.

Comment: I did that, and in the end I got 0/0.

Comment: You get $\frac{\frac{2}{t}-1+\frac{\sin t}{t}}{1+\frac{\cos t}{t}}$. On top, as $t\to -\infty$, the two end terms approach $0$, so the top approaches $-1$. Similarly, the bottom approaches $1$. So the whole thing approaches $-1$.

Comment: OHMYGOD I think I just crossed out t/t! Yes I checked the graph of it and it does approach -1! Thank you so much! LOL that was so stupid of me!

Comment: So does the NEGATIVE infinity have no bearing?

Comment: In this problem, basically the same calculation shows that the limit as $x\to\infty$ is also $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $|2+\sin t|\le 3$ and $|\cos t|\le 1$ for all $t$, so for $t$ of large absolute value the fraction is approximately $\dfrac{-t}t$.

Comment: Where did the absolute values come from? I'm really confused by this hint.

Comment: @Kaaagome: I could just as well have said that $1\le 2+\sin t\le 3$ for all $t$ and $-1\le\cos t\le 1$ for all $t$, not using absolute values at all. The point is that these parts are bounded, while the $-t$ and $t$ terms are not. Let me ask a simpler question: can you find $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1-t}{t-1}\;?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{2-t+\sin t}{t+\cos t}=\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{\frac2t-1+\frac{\sin t}{t}}{1+\frac{\cos t}{t}}=-1.$$

Why $\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 0$ and $\frac{\cos t}{t} \to 0$ as $t\to -\infty $?

You can use  the squeeze theorem  to get it.

Hints: As $t\to -\infty$,  $\frac1t\le \frac{\sin t}{t}\le -\frac1t$.